# How to convert php->json to c# class?

Tags: c#, php, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a json response to a C# class.
The problem is that the elements are named as `"1" , "2"` etc, which while converting to C# classes are creating problem as variables cannot be named `"1"`.
With out the same variable names the deserializing does not seem to work.

My array is in the form :

```
[{
    "0": "21838",
    "1": "2014-10-15",
    "2": "2014-10-15",
    "3": "745",
    "4": "140.00",
    "32": "140.00",
    "5": "140.00",
    "33": "140.00",
    "7": "0.00",
    "34": "0.00",
    "35": 0,
    "8": "30",
    "9": "10",
    "10": "6",
    "11": "0",
    "12": "0000-00-00",
    "13": "0.00",
    "36": "",
    "14": "1833",
    "15": "1",
    "16": "1",
    "17": "184",
    "18": "305",
    "19": "1",
    "20": "2264",
    "21": "3214",
    "22": {"0":"123"}
    /* etc, etc, etc */
}]
```

How can I deserialize this into a C# class?
*Updated ,the json has array of arrays

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deserialize to an array of dictionaries.

```
var json = "bla bla bla json";

var dictionaries = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(json);

foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
{
    foreach (var pair in dictionary)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(dictionaries[0]["0"]); // 21838
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew for the reply , I tried using your solution but it says "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String' during JSON deserialization"
I have tried using Newtonsoft.Json which throws the same exception.